# Why was "ein" used here after a masculine plural noun?

Tags: grammatical-case

> Er setzt sich falsche Zähne ein, [...]. -- [Source](http://www.nachrichtenleicht.de/film-preise-verliehen.2045.de.html?dram:article_id=385325)

If I am not wrong, *Zähne* is a masculine plural and hence I think the *ein* here is gilding the lily.

Comment: Germans do not *insert teeth*, they *set teeth in* ...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That *ein* at the end of the sentence corresponds to the *ein* contained in the separable verb *einsetzen*. There is no relation to articles whatsoever. Moreover, unlike other languages (Polish, French, Spanish, etc.), in German there is no *masculine plural*, every noun is collapsed, grammatically seen, to just *plural*.

Answer (score 11):

Here, *ein* is not the indefinite article, nor does it refer to the number *one*. Instead, it belongs to the separable verb ***ein**setzen*, a short form of ***hinein**setzen*, and it means to put something *in* or *into* something else.

Answer (score 6):

*Ein* has other responsibility in addition to what you know. In German language, there are separable and inseparable verb prefixes. (There is a good [handout](http://www.nthuleen.com/teach/grammar/sepinsepprefixexpl.html) to learn these prefixes).

As you also see in the tutorial, *ein* is a separable verb prefix. The verb in your example is *einsetzen*.

The other examples with *ein* could be;

> einschlafen - Ganz allein schlafe ich nicht ein
>
> einkaufen - Ich kaufe nicht mehr ein